# Two similar versions of the logarithmic derivative.

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, limits, functions, derivatives

We had a [discussion](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/53996339#53996339) in chat with Knight:

It got me thinking that the following two versions of the logarithmic derivative of a function might be true:

> Let $x=p$ be a pole of $f(x)$. Show that:
>
> $$-\frac{f'(x)}{f(x)}=\lim_{c\to 1} \, \left(\frac{f(x) f(c p)}{f(cp-p+x)}-f(c p)\right)$$
>
> Let $x=r$ be a root of $f(x)$. Show that:
>
> $$\frac{f'(x)}{f(x)}=\lim_{c\to 1} \, \left(\frac{f(x)}{f(c r) f(cr-r+x)}-\frac{1}{f(c r)}\right)$$

Are they?

Comment: When you say pole of $f(x)$, are you talking about $f$ holomorphic, i.e. complex analysis?

Comment: Yes holomorphic everywhere except at the pole. Function I have tried for the first case is the Riemann zeta function, and for the second case the sine function.

Comment: $$-\frac{\zeta '(s)}{\zeta (s)}=\lim_{c\to 1} \, \left(\frac{\zeta (c) \zeta (s)}{\zeta (c+s-1)}-\zeta (c)\right)$$   

$$\frac{\sin '(s)}{\sin (s)}=\lim_{c\to 1} \, \left(\frac{\sin (s)}{\sin (\pi c) \sin (\pi c+s-\pi )}-\frac{1}{\sin (\pi c)}\right)$$

Comment: I found this now: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss%E2%80%93Lucas_theorem
Factoring the right hand side (RHS) of the second equality in the proof in the Wikipedia page for the Gauss Lucas Theorem settles the question for polynomials for the second case in my question above.

Comment: $$-\psi ^{(0)}(s)=\lim_{c\to 0} \, \left(\frac{\Gamma (c) \Gamma (s)}{\Gamma (c+s)}-\Gamma (c)\right)$$